# What does it mean to "grab someone in the gut?"

Tags: meaning, slang, colloquialisms

Could anyone please help me know what is the meaning of "grabs people in the gut" in the following quote from Jim Collins’ *[Built to Last](https://www.jimcollins.com/concepts/bhag.html)*:

> A BHAG is a huge and daunting goal—like a big mountain to climb. It is clear, compelling, and people “get it” right away. A BHAG serves as a unifying focal point of effort, galvanizing people and creating team spirit as people strive toward a finish line. Like the 1960s NASA moon mission, a BHAG captures the imagination and *grabs people in the gut*.

Comment: Have you heard of a gut feeling?

Comment: Isn't to 'grab someone in the gut' broadly to speak to them in a way that sparks their deepest beliefs, desires or wishes?